# ERROR 1604 (42000)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a mysql commands

```
mysql> create table enrolled (snum int,cname varchar(20), primary key (snum,cname), 
        foreign key(snum) references student (snum), 
        foreign key (came ) references class (cname) 
        on delete cascade );
```

When I run it , I get an ERROR

> ERROR 1604 (42000) :You have an ERROR in your SQL syntax ; check manual  that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> create table enrolled ( sum int, cname varchar(20) primary key(snum ,cnam' at line 1

Comment: `came` !== `cname`

Comment: post create table statement of student and class

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
foreign key (came )
```

To this

```
foreign key (cname )
```

Comment: Now it showing like this. mysql >create table enrolled (sum int,cname varchar(20),primary key (snum,cname),foreign key(sum) references student (snum), foreign key (cname ) references class (cname) on delete cascade);

Comment: Now it's showing like this mysql > create table enrolled (snum,cname varchar(20), primary key(snum,cname) ' at line 1

Comment: Now it's showing like this mysql > create table enrolled (snum int,cname varchar(20), primary key(snum,cname) ' at line 1